# Sorted output inside a tabular

Tags: tables, environments

Currently I'm trying to create an environment with several different `\item`-like commands. I want the arguments of the different commands to be ordered by their type.

Basically the usage of

```
\begin{ordered}
  \fruit{Apple}
  \vegetable{Salad}
  \vegetable{Bell Pepper}
  \fruit{Strawberry}
\end{ordered}
```

should result in

```
Apple
Strawberry
Salad
Bell Pepper
```

With the following Code this can be done on a basic level

```
\newenvironment{ordered}{
  \newcommand{\fruits}{}
  \newcommand{\fruit}[1]{
    \begingroup\def\temp{\renewcommand{\fruits}}
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\temp\expandafter{\fruits{##1\\}}}
  \newcommand{\vegetables}{}
  \newcommand{\vegetable}[1]{
    \begingroup\def\temp{\renewcommand{\vegetables}}
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\temp\expandafter{\vegetables{##1\\}}}
}{
  \fruits
  \vegetables
}
```

However, If I want my ordered environment to open a tabular containing the fruits and vegetables I get problems:

```
\newenvironment{ordered}{
  ...
  \begin{tabular}{l}
}{
  \fruits
  \vegetables
  \end{tabular}
}
```

Results in `! Missing } inserted. <inserted text> } l.31 \end{ordered}`

Is there any way to use `\fruits` and `\vegetables` inside the ordered environment inside tabular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're including groups in your addition to `\fruits` and `\vegetables`. Instead, the `\g@addto@macro<cs>{<stuff>}` macro can help adding `<stuff>` to `<cs>` (it requires a [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fruits}{}
\newcommand{\fruit}[1]{\g@addto@macro\fruits{#1\\}}
\newcommand{\vegetables}{}
\newcommand{\vegetable}[1]{\g@addto@macro\vegetables{#1\\}}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{ordered}{%
  \renewcommand{\fruits}{\relax}\renewcommand{\vegetables}{\relax}% Clear fruits/vegetables
  \tabular{l}
}{%
  \expandafter\ifx\fruits\relax\else\fruits\hline\fi% Print fruits
  \vegetables% Prints vegetables
  \endtabular
}
\begin{document}

\begin{ordered}
  \fruit{Apple}%
  \vegetable{Salad}%
  \vegetable{Bell Pepper}%
  \fruit{Strawberry}%
\end{ordered}

\begin{ordered}
  \vegetable{Salad}%
  \vegetable{Bell Pepper}%
\end{ordered}

\end{document}
```

I've also removed some spurious spaces that are introduced from line breaks. For more on this see [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted. But now I have some kind of enhancement: what if I want to put an `\hline` between `\fruits` and `\vegetables`, but only if there is at least one fruit in `\fruits`?
I tried to check for empty `\fruits` by using `\IfStrEq{\fruits}{\empty{}}{}{\fruits\hline}` instead of `\fruits` but this results in `! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }. <inserted text> \par l.16 \end{ordered}`

Comment: @Marcel: I've updated my answer. It includes resetting `\fruits` and `\vegetables` to `\relax`, which is used for testing whether or not to insert an `\hline`.